# Weird gdb behaviour on Xcode 4.2 after moving to LLVM 3.0 and libc++

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode4, gdb, c++11

After swaping compiler to LLVM 3.0 and libc++ to have C++11 suport (unique_ptr is a little jewel :)) I have noticed gdb is not working properly when I try to print an object information. What I have tested is the following:

1) I have a std::vector < std::unique_ptr > member variable. If I set a breakpoint inside the class containing this member var and do a "print _reusableEntities.size()" I get this:

> Breakpoint 2, GameObjectMgr::createGameObject (this=0x0) at /Users/hexdump/Dropbox/Games prototypes/Re-World/src/ReWorld/Engine/EntityManagement/GameObjectMgr.mm:92
>   92          go=std::move(_reusableEntities.back());
>   The program being debugged stopped while in a function called from GDB.
>   When the function (GameObjectMgr::createGameObject()) is done executing, GDB will silently
>   stop (instead of continuing to evaluate the expression containing
>   the function call).

But if I have a line of code like:

```
int size=_reusableEntities.size()
```

it reads the size ok. It really seems a gdb problem when inspecting the vector size. In the other hand I can see how the vector contains correct values in the Local vars windows.

Another thing that is really weird is why the error shows information related to createGameObject function because It has nothing to do with the gdb command call and I wasn't inside it when trying to print the values.

It is really weird and a pain in the ass when debugging.

2) I have F7 configured to step over functions. This worked until I made this changes, now, it doesn't matter if I push F6 (step into) or F7 (step over) I'm always getting inside unique_ptr code when copying, or getting raw pointer from it :/.

If anyone could guess what is happening I would be really grateful, anyway, I know it is really difficult to guess from just my explanation. If anyone needs more info, please, ask for it.

Comment: That was first thing I did, switch to the other debugger, but it even works worse. It just shows disassembled code when trying to enter methods (even objc methods). This is crazy. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Are you using a recent version of gdb? Lately I also experienced weird behavior and upgrading solved the issue. I guess this was due to C++11 which old gdbs do not "understand".

Comment: Well this was posted some time ago. I will try again. Thanks.